# OutOfMemoryError Android

Tags: android

I made a small Game that frequently needs to change the background.
For example **setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.backgroundgame);**
Now I get the error that I ran out of memory so my question is how do I unload the previous background from the memory?

Comment: Make sure you're setting your 1) calling recycling the image once you're done with it, and/or setting the reference to null.  Though not recommended you might find yourself having to invoke the GC.collect() also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage collector should eventually delete the images when they are no longer needed. It sounds as though you want to call the `recycle()` method on the bitmap [(link)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) to free up the space more quickly.